# Applescript Objective C isn't outputting to variable

Tags: xcode, applescript

Using Xcode, I'm trying to pipe the output of a shell command that I use to check the list of available printers on a print server. It works in Terminal, but the output can only be seen in the debugger, and when I put the script into Script Editor, I get the output displayed as a "Syntax Error".

I'm trying to have it come up as an alert with the Display alert command but I've had no luck.

```
on Button_(sender)
set Printerlookup to  "/usr/local/bin/iprntcmd --listprintersonserver printerserver.com"
set Printers to do shell script Printerlookup
display alert "The available printers are:" & Printers
end Button_
```

EDIT:

This is the whole appdelegate.

```
script AppDelegate
property parent : class "NSObject"
property txtBox: ""
-- IBOutlets
property theWindow : missing value

on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened 
end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
    -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
    return current application's NSTerminateNow
end applicationShouldTerminate_
use scripting additions
on Button_(sender)
if txtBox is "" then
    display alert "Please enter some text"
    else
set iPrntlookup to  "/usr/local/bin/iprntcmd --listprintersonserver "& txtBox &"printerserver.com"
set Printers to do shell script Printerlookup
display alert "The available printers are:" & Printers as text
    end if

end Button_
end script
```

This is the expected output, which is found in the debugger area as opposed to the dialog box.

```
2018-05-07 21:34:12.925412+1000 iPrint Local[29523:430596] MessageTracer: 
Falling back to default whitelist
2018-05-07 21:34:17.104407+1000 iPrint Local[29523:430596] *** -[AppDelegate 
Button:]: iprntcmd v06.07.01
Listing printers on testprintserver.com.
ipp://testprintserver.com/ipp/printer1
ipp://testprintserver.com/ipp/printer2 (error 1)
```

Comment: is the return value a list? Add "as text" after "Printers" in the dialog to test it. Dialogs cannot show lists so you need to reformat the list to a text as you like.

Comment: The output follows a list structure. However when I add "as text" to the end I am still hit with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `use scripting additions` statement at the top of your script.

Comment: Just to clarify: the first `use` statement encountered in a script automatically disables scripting addition terminology (commands/type names), and `display alert` is a StandardAdditions scripting addition command. `use scripting additions` (re)enables scripting addition terminology.

Comment: I've added the statement to the top of my script and I'm still getting the same issue when in Script Editor, in xcode the code won't even compile.

Comment: OK, scratch that. I assumed it was the `do shell script` that wasn’t compiling, which happens when Standard Additions isn’t imported. As Cheesy says, that’ll happen if you’ve a `use` statement somewhere in the rest of your script. Your `Button_` handler compiles fine otherwise. Without seeing your original error message or surrounding code it’s hard to troubleshoot. If you can update your post with more detail you’ll get better responses.

Comment: Thanks @foo I think I've added all relevant information, apologies I'm new to this.

Comment: At a loss to why you get 'Syntax Error' when compiling in Script Editor, as the entire AppDelegate object compiles there (with or without `use scripting additions`) but never mind. Looking at the debugger output, I'm going to hazard a new guess that `iprintcmd` is writing its output to stderr instead of stdout (`do shell script` only captures the latter), which would be stupid but not impossible; in which case adding `2>&1` to the end of your shell script will get around that by redirecting stderr to stdout. Can't test myself it as I don't have iPrint, but try it and see.